# Cannot access datatable content jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am trying to send datatable data via ajax to my controller. 
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163194/how-to-get-jquery-datatables-content-to-mvc-controller) solution

However, When I debugged my code, I got this value in my parameter: **{string[0][]}**

Here's my ajax:

```
$('#save').click(function (evt) {
            var table = $('#orders').DataTable();
            var _content = table
                .rows()
                .data();

            console.log("Content is " + _content);

            var _tableContent = new Array();

            for (var i = 0; i < _content.length; i++) {
                _tableContent[i] = _content[i];
                console.log("data in array is " + _tableContent[i]);
            }


            var url = "/api/items";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    data: _tableContent
                },
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (reponse) {
                    alert("error : " + reponse);
                }
            });
```

And here's my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public string[][] TestList(string[][] data)
{

    return data;
}
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Change return type `string[][]` to `JsonResult` and use that to create `DataTable` content rows with `return Json(data)` (or serialize it first before returning JSON).

Comment: Additionally, `var url = "/api/items"` points to a Web API controller action named `items`, not `TestList` one. Use `/[ControllerName]/TestList` to call corresponding action method.

Comment: Hi Testsuya, My controller method "TestList" is actually getting hit every single time. So, I don't think I need to change the url. I guess it's because of the [HttpPost] tag.

Comment: Actually `type: "POST"` matches with controller action's `[HttpPost]`, so the controller will getting hit with proper naming. But I think the return type should be `JsonResult` instead of jagged array.

Comment: Okay, so I changed the return type to JsonResult and the parameter type to JsonResult. I got something like this: 

data: {System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult} 
ContentEncoding: null
ContenType:null,
Data: [object]

So now how do I get the data?

Comment: Use JSON.NET (`JsonConvert.SerializeObject`) to serialize it using custom converter, you can see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012831/how-to-create-json-arrays-of-jagged-objects-from-a-net-data-structure). What you're passing is jagged array which should treated differently from single array.

Comment: In order to create my own custom converter ,I need to see the content of the data I am passing. How can I view the contents in my ajax  before sending it to controller?

Comment: Is that `console.table(_tableContent)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(_tableContent));` enough to see table contents before passing to controller? You can see the output and make sure that data to be posted later is in right format.

Comment: When I do that I get a all the attributes with emptry values while I have one row in my table with values on it. {\"description\":\"\",\"productPrice\":\"\",\"isTaxable\":\"\"},\"quantity\":\"\",\"discount\":\"\",\"finalPrice\":\"\",\"lineItemTotal\":\"\"}]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180334/discussion-between-tetsuya-yamamoto-and-bangbang).